# ISA relationships in RDBMS

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

"Introduction to Database Management Systems" by Raghu Ramakrishnan and Johannes Gehrke contains following ER diagram:

[image]

> For example, we might identify a subset of employees as Senior Emps.
> We can  modify Figure 2.12 to reflect this change by adding a second ISA node as a  child of Employees and making Senior Emps a child of this node.

Why do we need another ISA node? Why don't we just add this new entity to the current ISA node? Does that matter?

Comment: Probably because the choices from any given ISA must be mutually exclusive. An employee is either hourly or contract. Toss in Senior and it isn't a third branch, it is a completely different type of ISA relationship.

Comment: @NealB so you are saying that since hourly and contract employees are related somewhat, we use the same ISA node, but is it wrong to use the same ISA node for SeniorEmployees or is it better to use another ISA node just for readability etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Can't we use the existing ISA node to create this relationship?"

(Disclaimer : read all of this a bit tongue-in-cheek.  ER was never really intended to be logically complete and precise in its expressive power, and moreover there are so many different ER dialects that it's hard to be absolutely certain of what some given dialect seeks to express, and how, and what it does not seek to express)

What you would lose is the characteristic of exclusiveness between the various IS_A "sub-entities".  Your example design as given is presumably intended to explicitly document the notion that an employee can never be both hourly_emp and contract_emp.

If an employee can be both "senior" and "contract", there is no exclusiveness between them, and if the ER dialect's IS_A triangle intend to express exactly such exclusiveness, then your solution would be wrong.

But (to repeat) note that none of this is actually cast in stone.  All depends on what the intended semantics are of the symbols used in your particular ER dialect.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the current ISA node (that is in the diagram above) determines how employees are paid, so simply add another one onto the current node doesn't make a whole lot of sense because SeniorEmployees can be either hourly or contract.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you would create any entities with an ISA relationship is to give the new entity additional attributes.

Just like in object-oriented modeling, you would create a new subclass so that the new class can have additional data or additional methods relative to its superclass.

So the implication of that example is that SeniorEmployees should have some new column(s), for instance to store an award for years of service or something.

If there are no new attributes that are unique to SeniorEmployees, I'd just treat them the same as regular Employees, no need to create a new child table.

Comment: Thanks, but actually that is not what i am asking. Let us say that SeniorEmployees have new attributes and we will create an ISA relationship. What i wonder is that, why do we need another ISA node? Can't we use the existing ISA node to create this relationship?

Answer (score 0):

Two advantages of ISA:

1. descriptive attribute specific to sub-class.
2. identity entities that participate in a relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Simply read ISA as "is a". Hourly employees ---> is a ---> employee (bottom up approach as  hourly employees and contract employees are generalized by employees).

For more details refer to "[Generalization, Specialization and Aggregation in ER Model](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/generalization-specialization-and-aggregation-in-er-model/amp/)".

Comment: This doesn't answer the question posed. The question was about why an additional ISA node was necessary; it was not a question about what "ISA" means.